# Why does this C loop skip the first attempt to input a letter?

Tags: c, function, loops

This is a program I am making for a class. It is supposed to read a letter from a file, and then in the game the user tries do guess the letter. with every wrong attempt the program tells you if the actual letter comes before or after your guess in the alphabet.

For some reason when I run it, the loop skips the first attempt in the getLetter function and does not let you input the letter. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MaxGuesses 5

void instructions();
int playGuess (char solution);
char getLetter ();
int compareLetters (char guess, char solution);

int main()
{

     int numGames;
     int i;
     char solution;
     char guess;
     int result;

     FILE *inFile;

     inFile=fopen("inputLet.txt","r");

     instructions();
     scanf("%d", &numGames);

     for(i=1; i<=numGames; i++)
     {
         printf ("\nThis is game %d\n", i);
         fscanf(inFile, " %c", &solution);
         result = playGuess(solution);

         if (result == 1)
             printf("You've WON!\n");
         else
             printf("You've LOST :(\n");

     }

     //close file
     fclose(inFile);
     return 0;
      }

      void instructions ()
      {
          printf ("This game consists of guessing letters.\nThe user will have up      to 5 chances of guessing correctly,\nupon every failed attempt,\na hint will be provided  regarding alphabetical position.\n\nEnter the number of games you wish to play (max 4): ");
 }

 char getLetter()
 {
     char userGuess;
     printf("\nPlease enter your guess: ");
     scanf("%c", &userGuess);
     userGuess = tolower(userGuess);
     return userGuess;
 }

 int compareLetters(char guess, char solution)
 {
     if (guess == solution)
         return 1;
     else if (guess < solution)
    {
         printf("\nThe letter that you are trying to guess comes before %c",    guess);
    return 0;
}
else if (guess > solution)
{
    printf("\nThe letter that you are trying to guess comes after %c", guess);
    return 0;
}
 }

 int playGuess (char solution)
 {
     int numGuesses = 0;
     int winOrLose = 0;
     char guess;
     while(numGuesses < MaxGuesses && winOrLose == 0)
     {
         guess = getLetter();
         winOrLose = compareLetters(guess, solution);
         numGuesses++;  
     }

     return winOrLose;
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be consuming a character left in the input buffer (possibly a newline or other whitespace character). You could try changing the format string from `"%c"` to `" %c"` as you've done elsewhere, which will skip all the whitespace characters in the buffer before trying to read a character.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! that was it! i have been going over and over the code and could not find this error. I really appreciate your help!